# I can't combine 2 javascript files into 1

Tags: javascript, button, local-storage, toggle

I have 2 javascript files and I want to combine them. One is for dark-mode and the other one is for dark-mode switch button. Separately they work fine, but when combined dark-mode works like it should, but switch button place isn't saved after refreshing the page. What can I do to fix that?

```
    /* DARK-MODE */

function myFunction() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}

(function() {
    let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.add(onpageLoad);
    document.getElementById("theme").textContent = "DarkMode";
    localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";
})();

function themeToggle() {
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

    let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    if (theme && theme === "dark-mode") {
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "");
    } else {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark-mode");
    }
    
    document.getElementById("theme").textContent = localStorage.getItem("theme");
};

    /* DM-BUTTON */
    
function App() {}

App.prototype.setState = function(state) {
  localStorage.setItem('checked', state);
}

App.prototype.getState = function() {
  return localStorage.getItem('checked');
}

function init() {
  var app = new App();
  var state = app.getState();
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('#toggle');

  if (state == 'true') {
    checkbox.checked = true;
  }

  checkbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
      app.setState(checkbox.checked);
  });
}

init();
```

```
<div class="toggle1">
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" class="dmbtn" id="toggle">
     <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Try moving `init();` into the `(function() {`

Comment: @Kinglish Unfortunately it didn't work, there is the same problem

Comment: If you add the relevant HTML (show the toggle), that might help illuminate...

Comment: I can't add a snippet, but added html code

Comment: I dunno. Put console.log() statements around to make sure that localStorage is storing the value, and that the init() function is firing...

Comment: All right, I think I have resolved the problem, but don't exaclty know how. It seems that there was a problem with this portion of code: (function() {
    let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.add(onpageLoad);
    document.getElementById("theme").textContent = "DarkMode";
    localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";
})(); but I just switched dark-mode and button parts of code and it works (button is on top now). Still, thanks for the help